# How to get XmlSerializer to deserialize a null <number/> with no nil marking

Tags: c#, nullable, xmlserializer

Trying to fix a bug in a third party API client consuming their third party API -- it's coming back with "There is an error in XML document (x, y)" which is this line: `<totalunresolveditems />`

When that isn't null, it shows up like: `<totalunresolveditems><![CDATA[2]]></totalunresolveditems>`

In the third party API Client code, I changed the item from this:

```
[XmlElement("totalunresolveditems")]
public int TotalUnresolvedItems { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
[XmlElement("totalunresolveditems", IsNullable = true)]
public int? TotalUnresolvedItems { get; set; }
```

But unfortunately that didn't help, the same error remains at that same point in the document. Not sure how to work around this other than removing this property completely or marking it with [XmlIgnore], which does do the trick at the expense of losing that particular data.

Seems like the problem is the field isn't being marked with a nil="true", but we have no control over that. Since this is purely to deserialize external data it doesn't seem like a surrogate field would help either.

Comment: ![CDATA[]] is not an [XmlElement] it is [XmlText].  Not sure why it have angle brackets since it is innertext.

Comment: Here is one possible solution, that involves creating a custom NullableInt class that implements IXmlSerializable: https://web.archive.org/web/20110825092054/http://alexscordellis.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-xmlserializer-to-deserialize-into.html

Comment: @jdweng - good point, but there are other int's in this class which are deserializing just fine from numbers contained in other ![CDATA[]] fields. It's only the nullable one that is causing an issue. Thanks to your comment though, I was able to change it to `public string TotalUnresolvedItems { get; set; }` and then make a `public virtual int? TotalUnresolvedItemsUint` that tries to parse the string value and return it, or returns a null if it can't parse it, so at least I have the data available. Thanks!